# Loading test with authorized user

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance-testing, identity, load-testing

How to create loading test at Visual Studio 2013 with next scenario:

1. User sign up - 1 time
2. Authorized User open specific page (main test target)

At global I want to do test under ASP.NET MVC web-site page which is required authorization. I use Identity.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Once your load test is ready, open it in VS and then right click on test mix in your scenario 1.  Check image above for more details.
Initialise test will be only run once for load test, and other web performance tests will be run multiple number of times.
Thanks.